# Maven doesn't install everything from the pom file resulting in "Missing Required Library" x 124

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

My pom.xml looks as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>be.ugent.sop.p404</groupId>
    <artifactId>P404</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>P404EJB</artifactId>
<name>P404EJB</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.40.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.databene</groupId>
        <artifactId>contiperf</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.databene</groupId>
        <artifactId>contiperf</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee-deployment_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<packaging>ejb</packaging>
```

As one of the examples of the problems I am receiving:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project 'P404EJB' is missing required library: '/home/zeesteen/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1/json-simple-1.1.1.jar'   P404EJB     Build path  Build Path Problem
```

I assumed that after using the following command:

```
mvn clean install eclipse:eclipse
```

Maven was supposed to fetch libraries that are in the pom and not present on my machine yet? (The folders, for example "com" don't exist in the .m2/repository folder)

I have tried multiple solutions myself such as 
- Removing the Maven nature, clean installing again, converting to a maven project
- Doing variations on the clean command
- Right clicking on the project and doing Maven > update Project
- Cleaning the project through eclipse

I got 124 Java Build Path Problems like the one mentioned above.

Comment: Is this running on a server?

Comment: This is running locally. The error comes from within eclipse

Comment: well you should make sure that you stop all running instances of your program and rerun it again. if that doesn't help, i don't know

Comment: it's probably worth doing a `mvn clean package` on the command line, then check the output from maven. There is also a switch for verbose logging. 

Either an `-e` or a `-X`, see the docs:
http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/faq.html#debug-maven

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake..

Maven didn't give errors because there was nothing wrong with my maven repo apparently. Eclipse had changed the location of my settings.xml maven file to a "nonexistent" location.. Resulting in all the problems. I manually changed it back and all problems are solved.

In Eclipse I did: 
Window > Preferences > Maven > User Settings: Field User Settings was wrong 
(eclipse changed it..) put it back to where I first made the settings, applied, cleaned the project and everything was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have added `Maven Dependencies` under `Libraries` in Java Build Path.

Note : You can check the properties by Right-clicking the project and click Properties. If it is NOT added, you can click `Add Library` and select `Maven Managed dependencies` and finish

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Oamhhau.png All the missing libraries are there but they're not in the folder structure of .m2, hence the red cross icon on some of them. Any way to force maven to download those?

Comment: Ok, Please post the error you get when you run `mvn clean install`?

Comment: Fixed it.. Look at my own answer for the fix. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Glad, you were able to fix it. These type of problems are hard to answer since they would have a lot of answers :)

Comment: Yeah I knew it was a long shot to ask on stackoverflow since it seemed one of those "hidden sneaky" problems.. But I had been searching for over 2 hours to find it and maybe someone who had something similar would have been able to help me immediately ^^